# Configure Wordpress on Azure Cloud Service to connect to Azure MySQL over SSL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure, ssl

We run Wordpress in a sub folder of our main .NET solution on a cloud service. We have moved our MySQL from CloudDB to Azure MySQL, however it will only connect if we set the "Enforce SSL Connection" to disabled.

The Wordpress wp-config.php has the following

```
define('DB_SSL', true);
```

I presume the issue is we need to pass a certificate, but it is not clear to me how we can set this in Wordpress so it is passed when connecting over SSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did:

1. [Obtain SSL certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl#step-1-obtain-ssl-certificate) and save the certificate file to the root of my Wordpress project.
2. Add the following into `wp-config.php`:

   ```
   define('DB_SSL', true);
   ```
3. Add this to the function `db_connect()` in my `wp-includes/wp-db.php`. It must be called before `mysqli_real_connect()`:

   ```
   // Just add this line
   mysqli_ssl_set($this->dbh, NULL, NULL, ABSPATH . 'BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem', NULL, NULL); 

   if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
       mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
   } else {
       @mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
   }
   ```

The solution seems a bit dirty but it works for me.

Comment: Modifying the core files of WP is not advised. What happens when WP is updated? Do we need to do this every time we upgrade WP?

Comment: Yes, we do need. But do you know any other solution without changing `wp-db.php` file to make this work?

Comment: I agree @Nitesh but don't see any alternative. As Aaron said, the solution is a bit dirty as it could be overwritten but it does at least solve the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

This will solve the issue by adding these lines to wp_config.php

```
define(‘MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS’, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
define(‘MYSQL_SSL_CA’, getenv(‘MYSQL_SSL_CA’));
define(‘MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS’, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL | MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT );
```

Comment: Thanks Anurag, I will try this, although it's now quite a long way down on my to do list, hence the slow reply (apologies).  Appreciate your input and will give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to be much simpler when using an Azure mySQL database server in conjunction with a Wordpress container image. If you're using a VPS this may not apply.

- Download the BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl
- Place the file in the root of your Wordpress install
- Add these two variables in wp-config:
- `define( 'MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL );`
- `define('MYSQL_SSL_CA_PATH','/');`

Comment: in my case it worked without adding define('MYSQL_SSL_CA_PATH','/');

Answer (score 1):

The solutions that work for me, add to wp-config.php:

PHP7.x

```
define( 'MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL | 
MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT ); 
define( 'MYSQL_SSL_CA', getenv('MYSQL_SSL_CA'));
```

PHP5.x

```
define('MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);
define( 'MYSQL_SSL_CA', getenv('MYSQL_SSL_CA'));
```

Source: https://jkudo.medium.com/how-to-connection-from-wordpress-installed-on-azure-app-service-to-azure-database-for-mysql-via-2b2c37c4a7de